# How can I limit the number of open AF_INET sockets?

Tags: networking, kernel, internet

Is there a way to limit the number of concurretly open AF_INET sockets (only)?
If so, how do I do it, and how will the networking behave if I'm above the limit?

For background: My cheap commodity router is a bit eager to detect 'syn flooding'. When it does, it crashes (and doesn't automatically restart itself). I'm thinking limiting concurrent connections to around 1000 should keep it from bickering.

Comment: SYN packets are only send when a new connection is created. A syn flood refers to a huge number of newly created connections in a short time. Concurrency connections is another thing. [This answer on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux/3923785#3923785) might help understanding how to limit concurrency connections.

Comment: I fixed my syn-flooding by 'updating' my netgears firmware to dd-wrt. It let me set settings for max connections and timeouts for tcp and udp direct on the router (it is the router crashing the wireless not the OS ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of connections at once by using iptables & the connlimit module.

From the iptables man page:

```
# allow 2 telnet connections per client host
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 23 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -j REJECT

# you can also match the other way around:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 23 -m connlimit ! --connlimit-above 2 -j ACCEPT

# limit the number of parallel HTTP requests to 16 per class C sized network (24 bit netmask)
iptables -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 24 -j REJECT

# limit the number of parallel HTTP requests to 16 for the link local network
(ipv6) ip6tables -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -s fe80::/64 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 64 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot. I was waiting for a an answer to this for quite some time. Now, the problem with my router is kind of hard to reproduce, so I'll just assume this works and accept it. It looks like it's just what I need to do.